# 'Hyperlinks.Add' method

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a piece of VBA code to check through a workbook to identify cells that do not satisfy certain criteria (e.g. < 0). I also created a summary tab to write all these cells' tab, row number and column number into a table. I also want like to create a hyperlink in the summary tab to link to the specific cell that has problem. Here is my code:

```
Cells(LastRow + 1, 6).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & tabName & _
"'" & "!R" & (j+1) & "C" & (i+1) & " ", TextToDisplay:="Link"
```

`tabName` is a string of the relevant tab name. `j` and `i` are variables.

It does create a hyperlink seems identical to a manual created one. But, click it will return a message that *Reference is not valid*.

Any suggestion what can I try to make the link work?

Comment: I just ran that and it works fine.  Maybe verify that tabName is the correct name of the tab.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed. It is the tab name causes the problem.